# swift NSMutableURLRequest https secure?

Tags: swift, swift2

In my app I am making an `https` request to an API. Is it safe to say that swift handles this connection properly and my traffic is secure from man in the middle attacks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how secure is NSURLConnection over https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940849/how-secure-is-nsurlconnection-over-https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only secure from MITM attacks if you also pin the certificate.

Essentially that is verifying that the endpoint you are connected to is the correct server. Proxies can stand in the middle, usually locally, and present their certificate and then make a connection to the server. It is TLS all the way but you are not talking directly to the server.

With pinning you verify that the certificate supplied by the server is the correct one, generally by having a copy of the correct certificate in the app and verifying certain fields or the whole certificate.

Network analyzers such as Charles Proxy can be MITM and thus examine th edata being sent and received. Pinning to the server stopes this attack.

Comment: I added more to the answer.

Comment: So swift wont handle this automatically? I'm not sure how I would go about  'pinning' the certificate in swift. Does it help that the server I am connection to is my own and I wrote the API?

Comment: It is not a Swift issue, the same applies to Objective-C. And you have to provide a copy of the certificate or information from the certificate, that can't be handled automatically. But you may want to examine if MITM attacks are a concern to you. Evaluate the attacker's resources and capabilities, how much your data is worth to you in $$ and reputation, also to your users. Security is all about work factor, that is how much work will be required to successfully make an attack. It is virtually impossible to have 100% security. And then how secure is the server and server login?

Comment: Note: The UL time to breach a Class III bank vault is only 120 minutes! How can that be safe? The safety is a second factor, the guard that inspects the vault every hour. The work factor is greater than the guards rounds. But still there are bank vault robberies.